# Building self contained classes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a bunch of classes that are used by a lot of my projects. Some of these classes have to access some other special classes that I have created. Because I want to make the classes as much independent of others I do not want to have #import lines to cross import classes that do not belong together. I would like to access information on those classes without having to use #import lines.

Apple has some special stuff that can be accessed without importing anything. For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

or

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

how do I create classes like that. Classes that I can simply do a

```
[[MyClass sharedClass] property]
```

or

```
[[MyClass sharedClass] runThis]
```

and have access to it. Without having any #import line.

**Attention because I am not talking about a regular singleton. A singleton you have to still import its file.**

Is this possible?

Comment: You keep classes "decoupled" from each other by an appropriate design, not by not importing mandatory headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't see an import for those classes is because you have the UIKit framework as a part of your project, which is effectively importing those classes' .h files into *every* class you create. It is possible to do what you are describing, however, in terms of separation, by taking advantage of dynamic dispatch and dynamic typing in objective-c, however you will lose compile-time error checking.

For example, I have a subclass of UIApplication delegate with an NSManagedInstance property by the name "managedObjectInstance. I do not import this subclass's .h file, but instead use the valueForKey: method like so:

```
[((NSObject*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) valueForKey: @"managedObjectContext"];
```

The NSObject cast is just because the delegate property of sharedApplication is an id, which means that it doesn't necessarily conform to KVO. To call a method that you know exists on a class without provoking a warning, you can use the performSelector: family of functions like so

```
[objectOfSomeClassWeDidntImport performSelector: @selector(amethodWeKnowExists)]
```

Comment: ok, this may be near to what I want but you are accessing a variable on the delegate. How do you access something (property, method or ivar) on a random class?

Comment: properties you would do via KVO like i said in the first example; managedObject is a property in this case. See my edit for your next question. I've never encountered a scenario with an ivar... but then again, how are you getting it in the first place from outside your class without a method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it....

Just make your imports in **`projectName-Prefix.pch`** file

and use the content of imported file wherever you want.

You can find `.pch` file in Resources folder.